# Automation Runbook for national cloud environment

Tags: azure-automation, runbook

I am trying to create a powershell runbook on the west europe region for stopping VMs in a national cloud environment AzureGermanCloud. Here the code for the authentication

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $CredentialAssetName
if(!$Cred) {
    Throw "Could not find an Automation Credential Asset named   '${CredentialAssetName}'. Make sure you have created one in this Automation Account."
}

#Get the Azure environment with the above name from the Automation Asset store
$Env = Get-AutomationVariable -Name $AzureEnvironmentName
if(!$Env) {
     Throw "Could not find an Azure environment '${AzureEnvironmentName}'."
}

$Account = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred -EnvironmentName $Env
```

From my powershell console that works but when I test it from the portal it says:

**Add-AzureRmAccount : Unable to find environment with name 'AzureGermanCloud'**

Is there any restriction to access national cloud environments from other environment...or maybe I am missing something?

Thanks,

PGR

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.profile/v2.5.0/add-azurermaccount) the only valid values are "AzureCloud" and "AzureChinaCloud".

You need to define an environment as "AzureGermanCloud" using the [Set-AzureRmEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.profile/v2.5.0/set-azurermenvironment) cmdlet, and then use `-EnvironmentName`, as you were before, to specify it.